# Magento 2.4.4: Discount on shipping amount not working with Paypal Payments Pro

Tags: magento2, shipping, discount, paypal-payments-pro

I have created a Cart price rule with coupon code with condition where 85% discount is applied to the total. I have also enabled "Apply to Shipping Amount". When I placed an order the discount is applied correctly, however, I am charged wrong.